# How to undervolt nvidia GPU in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am doing some deep learning but unfortunately, the design of my nvidia gpu makes it run pretty hot (~80°C), which is no temperature I want to keep for hours.

In Windows I used MSI Afterburner to lower the voltage, which makes the gpu run way cooler. Now I am looking for a way to do the same in Ubuntu.

I do NOT want to lower the power level, as other threads suggest, I want the same speed but at a lower voltage, which is possible under Windows.
Also, under Windows I was able to set a max clock via Msi Afterburner, that feature would be absolutely awesome!

Any ideas? Thanks alot!